# Calculating the median for a data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the below data.frame and I would like to identify the median value of the index.
For example, let's consider the below data.farme.

```
 index t1 t2 t3 t4
   10  1  4  7 10
   20  2  5  8 11
   30  3  6  9  0
   40  0  0  0  0
```

In the `first step,` I would like to add up by columns of the `data.frame.`

```
index t
10    22
20    26
30    18
40    0
```

In the `second step` I would like to identify the median of the index. In doing this I need to order t in increasing order and select the median.

```
index t
40    0
30    18
10    22
20    26
```

I know that there is a median function in R but I receive different results.

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(index=c (10,20,30,40), 
                   t1 = c(1, 2, 3, 0), 
                   t2 = c(4, 5, 6, 0), 
                   t3 = c(7, 8,9,  0),
                   t4 = c(10, 11, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
                                                            
df
```

Comment: `median(c(40, 30, 10, 20))` returns `25` because the vector is first sorted to `c(10, 20, 30, 40)`. This is, the median will be `(20 + 30) / 2 = 25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this :

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)
df_c <- df[,t:=t1+t2+t3+t4][, .(index, t)]
setorder(df_c, index)
median(df_c$index)
```

For the median I would actually use a function and apply to the index column.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: use the `apply` function

```
df$t<-apply(df[,c("t1","t2","t3","t4")],1,sum)
df
#          index t1 t2 t3 t4  t
#        1    10  1  4  7 10 22
#        2    20  2  5  8 11 26
#        3    30  3  6  9  0 18
#        4    40  0  0  0  0  0
```

Step 2: sort by column "t" using the `order` function

```
df<-df[order(df$t),]
df
  index t1 t2 t3 t4  t
# 4    40  0  0  0  0  0
# 3    30  3  6  9  0 18
# 1    10  1  4  7 10 22
# 2    20  2  5  8 11 26
```

Step 3 compute the `median` (I just saw [Peter's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11747575/peter) answer and I agree with him, that the median should be 25):

```
median(df$index)
# [1] 25
```